# In this code when I select provinces it appears all cities in the province thats the problem how I fix this? using javascript only

Tags: javascript

**html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Farhan</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--Create select with province list-->
<select id="province">
    <option value="">Select Province</option>
    <option value="Sindh">Sindh</option>
    <option value="Punjab">Punjab</option>
    <option value="Balochistan">Balochistan</option>
    <option value="Khyber Pakhtunkhwa">Khyber Pakhtunkhwa</option>
    <option value="Gilgit-Baltistan">Gilgit-Baltistan</option>
</select>
<!--Create select with city list-->
<select id="city">
    <option value="">Select City</option>
</select>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

As you can see when I select province it appears all the cities in an array means ,when I select Sindh then it select right cities but when I select Punjab it select cities of Punjab but cities of Karachi also visible they are not disappearing.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    console.log("Hello World");
    //Create javascript object with pakistan provinces
    let pakistan = {
        "Sindh": [
            {"Karachi" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]},
            {"Hyderabad" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]},
        ],
        "Punjab": [
            {"Lahore" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]},
            {"Islamabad" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]},
            {"Faisalabad" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]}
        ],
        "Balochistan": [
            {"Quetta" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]},
            {"Sibi" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]},
            {"Karakoram" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]}
        ],
        "Khyber Pakhtunkhwa": [
            {"Peshawar" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]},
            {"Mardan" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]},
            {"Kohat" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]}
        ],
        "Gilgit-Baltistan": [
            {"Kundian" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]}
        ]
    };
    //On change of province display cities in console
     document.getElementById("province").onchange = function () {
            let cities = pakistan[this.value];
            console.log(cities);
            cities.forEach(function (city) {
            let currentCity = Object.keys(city)[0];
            //Create option element for cities and append to select element
            let option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = currentCity;
            option.innerText = currentCity;
            
            document.getElementById("city").appendChild(option);
        });
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You had to empty the select before populating it again when the province changed.

This is the only part I added to the change event handler:

```
for (const option of document.querySelectorAll('#city > option')){
  option.remove();
}
```

```js
console.log("Hello World");
//Create javascript object with pakistan provinces
let pakistan = {
  "Sindh": [
      {"Karachi" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]},
      {"Hyderabad" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]},
  ],
  "Punjab": [
      {"Lahore" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]},
      {"Islamabad" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]},
      {"Faisalabad" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]}
  ],
  "Balochistan": [
      {"Quetta" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]},
      {"Sibi" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]},
      {"Karakoram" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]}
  ],
  "Khyber Pakhtunkhwa": [
      {"Peshawar" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]},
      {"Mardan" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]},
      {"Kohat" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]}
  ],
  "Gilgit-Baltistan": [
      {"Kundian" : ["Korangi", "Kotli", "Shah Faisal"]}
  ]
};
//On change of province display cities in console
document.getElementById("province").onchange = function () {
      
      //this will remove any options inside the select
      //before populating it again with the cities of the current prov.
      for (const option of document.querySelectorAll('#city > option')) 
      {
        option.remove();
      }

      let cities = pakistan[this.value];
      console.log(cities);
      cities.forEach(function (city) {
      let currentCity = Object.keys(city)[0];
      //Create option element for cities and append to select element
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = currentCity;
      option.innerText = currentCity;

      document.getElementById("city").appendChild(option);
  });
};
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Farhan</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--Create select with province list-->
<select id="province">
    <option value="">Select Province</option>
    <option value="Sindh">Sindh</option>
    <option value="Punjab">Punjab</option>
    <option value="Balochistan">Balochistan</option>
    <option value="Khyber Pakhtunkhwa">Khyber Pakhtunkhwa</option>
    <option value="Gilgit-Baltistan">Gilgit-Baltistan</option>
</select>
<!--Create select with city list-->
<select id="city">
    <option value="">Select City</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Comment: i dont want query in this

Comment: what do you mean? what is query? you said you had the problem that when changing province, the cities in the other select were adding up. In this demo they don't anymore and I just added one for loop in top of the change event handler.

Comment: maybe you meant you don't want to use `document.querySelectorAll`? did you want to retrieve the city select as a sibling of the `event.target`?? I think you should be clear if you want people to spend their time to help you.

Comment: by the way I highlighted the problem in your script.. if you prefer to loop the children of the city select grabbed throught getElementById is still the same. You can do it by yourself.